# How to use comma(,) as a value for a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to use comma as value for a variable in bash ;

Code:

```
    a=xyz
    y=pqr
    seprator=','
    string=$a$seprator$y
    echo $string

    Output is:
    xyz pqr

Expected output:
xyz,pqr
```

Please help,Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have `IFS` set to comma. See this example:

```
IFS=,
echo $string
xyz pqr

unset IFS
echo $string
xyz,pqr
```

However it is highly recommended to quote your variable like

```
echo "$string"
```

Even this `IFS=,` will work with quoted variable:

```
IFS=,
echo "$string"
xyz,pqr
```

Comment: @anusngh, the question is: _why on earth do you have `IFS` set to `,`?_ you very likely globally set `IFS` somewhere in your script, and this is not good! fix your script!

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine for me

```
#!/bin/sh

a=xyz
y=pqr
seprator=','
string=$a$seprator$y
echo $string


[root@HOFVW2090 data]# ./test.sh
xyz,pqr
```